# ASP.NET, log file and database - need tips

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, file

I'm planning to develop an application that will read a log file and display statistics.

The first question, I guess, is to know if I need a database or not?
Will it be quicker to run queries against the database ; or read the file each time a user wants to see the statistics?

If I choose the database method, I will have to read the log file and update the database on a regular basis (between 1 and 10 minutes). 
Is this article still good do you think (as it's from 2005): http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx
Or is it better to develop a Windows service? In that case, can I add the Windows Serice in my ASP.NET project in Visual Studio, or does it need to be

Comment: Have you thought about using something like splunk or simular (http://www.splunk.com/download/?ac=ga0508_s_splunk&_kk=splunk&_kt=0d0ee68f-00b5-441f-966d-e7b6c9228ad1&gclid=CIycgbjErqoCFRJc4Qod7Ue35w)

Comment: Splunk looks good. But if my protoype works fine, then I'm considering selling my software ...

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned `ASP.NET` so I believe it is a web application. In such case I would suggest to use Data Base, this is more robust, flexible and distributed solution. 
Any way consider using [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and then you can easily switch on file/DB ouput in any time by simply adding an other one appender section into the configuration file.

Comment: I have no control of the generated log file. And the log file changes all the time ; can be several times per minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> If I choose the database method, I will have to read the log file and
>   update the database on a regular basis (between 1 and 10 minutes)

Exactly, you're going to have to do it anyway. The Database basically just becomes another bottleneck at that point. For this type of app, there's no need to do anything other than read the file when the user requests to see it, and display them the results on the fly.

No need to have a windows service either. I mean, I don't know all your details, but I'm assuming the log file is in a directory on your machine, so just access it, open it, parse it, and display it to the user when they choose to see it on the front end.

Comment: Yes, the log file will be on the server. But the log file changes frequently.

Comment: Yeah that's fine. This way you will be always accessing the latest revision of the file. No need to keep track of the changes every 5 minutes if the user isn't requesting them.

Answer (score 0):

If the only data you going to work is LOG files, you don't need any database.

But I assume that your application would do parse logs files, create some statistics and STORE it somewhere, to make possible to users to get back and see statistics for some period of time. It is not cool if any time you will be "re-calculating" that statistics again (further more, you might loose original log files till that time).

Even if you could store it to some files also, I do not recommed that at all. Don't be afraid of using Database, don't be concered on application performace on such early stage. Do the most that helps you to solve the problem.. and as for me using Database will solve your problem;

Comment: The idea of the database is to replicate the log file ; and then run the querries more easily ...

Comment: The idea of the database is to replicate the log file ; and then run the querries more easily ... Also, I'm not sure how a web application will cope if the log file grows to 10MB ...

Comment: This is exactly what I said - why you minus that ?

Comment: Hi, I haven't 'minussed' your response. Or if I did, it wasn't on purpose. I have no idea how to minus a response ... sorry